# Regex Replace Double Double Quotes in json

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to replace double double quotes in case like this **""something""**, in json where empty value is possible case("somthingElse":"")?

I tried with `str = str.replace( /\""/g, '"' )`, but this one replace the empty value in my json and i get syntax error.

Example: `{"name":"name","price":"","job":""Developer""}`

Result: `{"name":"name","price":","job":"Developer"}`

Comment: It would probably be easier to remove the extra quotes wherever the JSON is coming from ?

Comment: @t.niese ye i get parse error now and have to replace the double quotes to fix it, but without the empty strings.
Its result from API, and i can't edit it at the back-end. That's why i am looking for string replace at the front-end.

Comment: Try [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lW7dL5/1).

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON to a javascript object, if so it would be trivial to just replace the quotes after parsing, before using the value ?

Comment: I would guess that the API has a problem with quotes in general, so you should expect that you might also get something like this `"job":"The "Developers""`, so even if the regexp of `stribizhev` will work for you right now, you should talk to the person that maintains the API to get that problem fixed in the API.

Comment: @t.niese ahhh you are right :(

Comment: You'd have to write a similar-to-JSON parser for this, a regex won't do because it's not a regular language.

Comment: @Petroff: So, there are entries like `"job":"The "Developers""`? Sorry, I do not think you can solve it with regex then.

Comment: @stribizhev yes, i was forgot about that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to parse, since the grammar is ambiguous and a result can be interpreted in two different ways. If we replace `Developer` in your example with a hand crafted value `"", "Developer":""` we get:

```
{"name":"name","price":"","job":"", "Developer":""}
```

Which means developer is a field. So unless you can guarantee `"` does not appear in the string the grammar is ambiguous.

#### Fix your backend instead :)

If I had to guess your backend is hand-making JSON, I've yet to see a case where this is preferable to using a serialization library.